# Media Element - Dynamic Loading of Audio

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I am using MediaElement to handle the fallback from FF, Chrome, IE9 to IE8 & 7. Everything runs very smooth, till the time i am working with audio and video as a Tag inside HTML, as soon I move the logic to JS, i am struggling.

Problem:
I am not able to change the Audio URL at runtime. I have tried setSRC, but without luck :(

It would be great if anyone can share same code to do the request task.

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Attach error message, or something else, please.

By the way, to change source you should use `setSrc()` (case sensitive) method of mediaelements player instance.